# Output server and other logs to the browser

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I am facing a challenge with my current project.We have it on an ec2 instance and we have a dev and a production server.Now the challenge is,whenever a team member encounters an error on the server I have to connect to the server using SSH(putty) and go to the logs folder and open the logs files using

```
   tail -f path/to/the/file
```

Now I want to have the logs easily accessible to the entire team,and would like to display them at an URL like **www.mydomain.com/logs/apache** or **/mysql**,so that there is no need of SSH every time.
I do not want the SSH keys distributed between multiple people as it can be a security concern and hence cannot share production details with all.
Also,making a SSH connection each time is time consuming.I am not a proficient linux/unix developer and like to seek help to understand if I can achieve this by any mean.Either by using a command or a shell script which writes the details of the logs to a file which is accessible over http.

Thank you

Comment: Looking forward for suggestions if what I am trying is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've created symbolic links to /var/log/ areas so that Apache will serve the files. EG:

```
# ln -s /var/log /var/www/logs
```

You probably should consider some form of security on this logs folder, especially if publicly visible.

Comment: Yes if I have to display it in the browser I will restrict it using `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I am looking forward to output the logs on the browser!